# python - Convert time into z mins from x hours y mins format

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Google API returns time in **x hours y mins** fomrat. I want to convert it to **z mins**. What is the most pythonic way to get this result?

Sample Response from Google API:

```
{
  "destination_addresses": [
    "Hamburg, Germany"
  ],
  "origin_addresses": [
    "85748 Garching, Germany"
  ],
  "rows": [
    {
      "elements": [
        {
          "distance": {
            "text": "761 km",
            "value": 760831
          },
          "duration": {
            "text": "7 hours 1 min",
            "value": 25242
          },
          "duration_in_traffic": {
            "text": "6 hours 42 mins",
            "value": 24145
          },
          "status": "OK"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": "OK"
}
```

Expected output:
duration_in_traffic "6 hours 42 mins" -->6*60+42 = 402 min

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to get the string value as a numeric so that you can further use it...

```
"duration_in_traffic": {
    "text": "6 hours 42 mins",
    "value": 24145
}
```

The value here is already numeric, it represents the seconds.
So 24145/60 = 402.416 minutes

That part of the work it done for you.

Now what will you do with this value :)

Comment: hello thanks a lot for your answer what exactlly i want is python code how return this value --  that mean to got the output of google as input to the python and to return this value

Comment: in simple word - how i can python cod have this data (google API) and all what the cod return is : 24145 (in this case)